# Function to use projections in legacy algorithms

Tags: c++, c++20, stl

I love the "projections" introduced by the ranges library, and I would like to use them in algorithms that haven't been rangeyfied yet.

I had the idea of using them through a function like this:

```
#include <utility>
#include <functional>

template<typename TFn, typename TProj = std::identity>
auto
constexpr proj(TFn &&Fn, TProj &&Proj = {})
{
  return [&Fn, &Proj]<typename... TArgs>(TArgs &&...Args)
  {
    return std::invoke(std::forward<TFn>(Fn),
                       std::invoke(std::forward<TProj>(Proj), std::forward<TArgs>(Args))...);
  };
}
```

This function enables writting, for example:

```
  std::sort(std::execution::par_unseq, v.begin(), v.end(), proj(std::less{}, &Pair::Key));
```

instead of:

```
  std::sort(std::execution::par_unseq, v.begin(), v.end(), [](auto const &lhs, auto const &rhs) { return lhs.Key < rhs.Key; });
```

Comment: Welcome to the Code Review Community where we review working code from a project you have written and suggest improvements for that working code. This does not seem to be a review of working code and appears to be too theoretical in nature.

Comment: @pacmaninbw The function `proj` does work, and IMHO is a useful piece of a library.  I've just seen a 2D vector template class in another question, which is just another library component. What's the difference? I realize that maybe the example I posted was misleadingly too long, so that I've simplified it to just show the usefulness of the function. Please let me know if now it looks better and otherwise I'll delete the question.

Comment: Simplification is actually worse. We need to see the code in its natural habitat. Please take a look at our [FAQ on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Design review

I don’t think you gave a lot of thought to what this library would be actually *useful* for.

Let me start by just considering the idea of `proj()` in complete isolation, ignoring any real-use context, and just considering it as a clever trick. From that perspective, I’d have to say that `proj()` is not a bad idea… but perhaps not the best way to go about it.

Here’s what a ranges call to `sort()` might look like:

```
std::ranges::sort(b, e, {}, &Pair::Key);
```

Here’s what `proj()` promises, at best:

```
std::sort(b, e, proj(std::less{}, &Pair::Key));
```

Here’s what else is possible in C++17, and possibly even before if you’re willing to put in the work of re-implementing `std::invoke`, etc. (of course it’s also possible in C++20, but… we’ll get to that issue shortly):

```
myns::sort(b, e, {}, &Pair::Key);
```

That is, you could implement a wrapper around `std::sort()` that handles the projection transparently.

For the user, that’s shorter, simpler, and doesn’t require manually specifying the comparator.

Not to mention that when I *can* advance to C++20 and use the full power of `std::ranges`, all I need to do (very basically) is a find-replace for `myns` to `std::ranges`. If I had these little `proj()` sub-calls everywhere, the code transform becomes *MUCH* more complex, and possibly tedious and/or dangerous.

And while you’re at it, why not implement `myns::sort()` as a [neibloid](https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2020/12/19/cpo-niebloid/#niebloids-solve-undesired-adl), to get all the sweet, sweet benefits that go along with that?

So if you *really* want the benefits of projections, why wouldn’t you do that?

Yes, I realize I’m basically saying “re-implement `std::ranges`”. As a halfway solution `proj()` only halfway satisfies. What’s the point of that? If you’re going to implement a library tool to make coders’ lives easier, why half-ass it? Who benefits from a mediocre solution? I guess the person writing the library gets to save on some work… but the whole point of library writing is that the library writer is taking on extra work so library *users* don’t have to. Making things easier for the library *writer* is silly. You should be concentrating on making things easier for the *users*.

And by the way, there are a bunch more complications to making something like `proj()` generally usable that I haven’t mentioned. Like, you’ve created a variant that works with most of the standard algorithms… but it won’t work with `std::find()` (no predicate, so no `Fn`). Won’t work with `std::merge()` (has a predicate, but has *two* projections). By the time you sort all that out, and test it all rigorously enough to show that it’s trustworthy in production code, you might as well have just used [`range-v3`](https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/).

Except… and this is the biggest issue with this whole idea…

This code won’t even compile in C++17. It needs C++20. C++20… where… `std::ranges` already exists.

***So who exactly is this library for?***

- It can’t be for C++17 (or before) users. (Won’t compile.)
- It makes no sense for C++20 (and later) users. (Because if they want a projection in a legacy algorithm, they can just use the `std::ranges` version. In your example, `std::ranges::sort()`.)

Are you targeting the hypothetical subset of users who are targeting C++20 with their project, but are using a C++20 compiler/library that has lambda templates, `std::identity`, and `constexpr` `std::invoke`… but *not* the ranges algorithms? That’s a bizarre target group, to say the least. I mean, who targets a C++ version—or uses a specific feature, like projections—without a compiler/library that actually supports it? Not to mention it’s a rather ephemeral group, because presumably if they’re targeting C++20, they could just use `std::ranges` as soon as the features they need become available in their chose compiler/library, making `proj()` just a weird stop-gap they would use for a while, then have to weed out of their code base later.

The bottom line is: `proj()` makes no sense. The only people who *could* use it… don’t really need it.

(Or, *AT BEST*, they could maybe use it *NOW*, for the brief period when their chosen platform supports everything needed to make `proj()` work, but doesn’t include `std::ranges`. But, frankly, I’d rather write the lambda than use a mysterious 3rd-party library that’s only going to be useful for a few months then become a legacy maintenance burden.)

From where I’m sitting, this looks like a case of [nerd sniping](https://xkcd.com/356/). A neat little theoretical problem became so distracting by its intellectual challenge, that you completely ignored the surrounding real-world problems that are, in point of fact, much more important.

## Code review

There’s not much code to review, of course, but….

```
auto
constexpr proj(//...
```

It’s pretty bizarre to write the `constexpr` after the `auto`. I’ve never seen that done before. I can’t see any sensible reason to adopt this style; it’s only likely to cause confusion.

```
constexpr proj(TFn &&Fn, TProj &&Proj = {})
```

Putting the type modifiers next to the variable name, rather than with the type, is a C convention, not a C++ convention. In C++, types matter more, so it makes more sense to say `TFn&& Fn`.

Also, it is a little peculiar to name *variables* with UpperCamelCase. UpperCamelCase is usually reserved for template argument names. In other words, `TFn&& fn` is more conventional.

```
template<typename TFn, typename TProj = std::identity>
auto
constexpr proj(TFn &&Fn, TProj &&Proj = {})
{
  return [&Fn, &Proj]<typename... TArgs>(TArgs &&...Args)
  {
    return std::invoke(std::forward<TFn>(Fn),
                       std::invoke(std::forward<TProj>(Proj), std::forward<TArgs>(Args))...);
  };
}
```

The thing that bothers me most about this function is that you:

1. take the two function arguments as forwarding references
2. place them into the closures as lvalue references; then
3. forward them within the closure.

Now, I will admit here that I haven’t sat down and reasoned this through as hard as it really deserves (because it’s late, and because I don’t see the point of the function in any case), but even from a cursory inspection it *smells* wrong. The smelly part is that you “forget” you’re dealing with forwarding references on that second step.

If the two parameters are lvalues, then no harm, no foul. All the forwarding references will collapse to lvalue references, and the `forward()`s will degenerate to… well, nothing, effectively; just lvalue references. So you have lvalue references all the way through. All cool.

But if a parameter is an rvalue, then the `forward()`s will degrade to rvalue references, and *may* end up *moving* the argument. So imagine you have a call to, say, `sort()`, where `proj()` has been given an rvalue function object (for either parameter, doesn’t matter). On the first execution of the comparator—that is, the first time that lambda `proj()` returns is called—it will *move* the function object… leaving it in a moved-from state… so the second time the comparator/lambda is executed, it’s using an “empty” function object. Exactly what damage this will cause depends on what using a “moved-from” function object means, which will depend on the function object type. But in any case, it’s not good.

Okay, put simply:

- You have correctly taken the function arguments as forwarding references…
- … and you have correctly perfect-forwarded them in the `invoke()` expressions…
- … but you have ***NOT*** perfect-forwarded them in the lambda capture.

You need perfectly-forwarded lambda captures. That is *NOT* trivial… but not *too* hard (tip: use `std::tuple` and a mother-ton of `decltype(TFn)`, etc.; don’t forget to mark the lambda `mutable`).

## Summary

As an experiment to explore stuff like projections and perfect-forwarding, this is actually a really neat idea.

As a practical library… I’m not seeing it. Just about the only people who could use it won’t need it. And the tiny demographic who could use it, but who can’t use the superior `std::ranges` solution, would be unwise to use it (better to wait until their platform supports `std::ranges`).

The implementation is sound but for that one tricky hiccup: You have perfectly-forwarded everything except the lambda captures. Fix that, and I *think* it should be a sound implementation. For full practical usability (such as it is), you’d need a couple of overloads for cases not covered by a single predicate and a single projection (for example, an overload without a predicate, for things like `std::find()`, `std::count()`, `std::remove()`, etc.; plus a few other overloads for the more esoteric cases), but once you’ve got the one working, that should be no problem.

Comment: Thanks for the review! I want this function mostly for parallel algorithms, which I believe won't be rangeyfied until at least C++26. You're right that the perfect forwarding of the functors is either useless or simply plain wrong. I misread https://stackoverflow.com/a/26831637

Comment: "It’s pretty bizarre to write the constexpr after the auto" I would also not write it that way for constexpr but it's conistent to C++'s clockwise rule. Good answer though!

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend using anything complicated—anything that hides what’s going on or buries it in layers of indirection—with parallel algorithms… but then, I wouldn’t recommend using parallel algorithms at all, so… .